# Equivalent to AbstractTableModel in c#

Tags: c#, java, abstracttablemodel

As title says, is there equivalent to AbstractTableModel in c#, or is there another, better, solution for creating table model in c#?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After working with Java Swing and C# WPF and SilverLight, IMHO there is no equivalent of `AbstractTableModel` in .Net. You simply set the `ItemsSource` property and use binding to map columms to properties. You can use `PagedCollectionView` to have some features like sorting and grouping, but the model still is a list of objects, so you have flexibility to pass any kind of collection of objects to the table.

Why do you want to use `AbstractTableModel` in C#, wich feature do you want to use or implement?

Comment: Column and row count(row count out of list that's created by reading all the data from one of the tables from db) and column names.

Comment: Try `DataTable` or another described in `DataSource` property instead of direct, raw `ItemsSource`: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagrid.datasource.aspx